I have an issue with creating a pubsub event from Omniscript to a LWC component
I have an issue when trying to create a pubsub event from an omniscript to lwc. I have imported the pubsub library from omnistudio namespace and then registered with omniscript action but when the omniscript runs an error shows up the register function is undefined within the pubsub. Am I missing something ? Appreciate any help.
1.PNG

2.PNG

3.PNG


You're trying to import an export called pubsub, but pubsub is the "default" export, not a named export. You need to import the default export.
// import { pubsub } from 'omniscript/pubsub'; // named export is incorrect
import pubsub from 'omniscript/pubsub'; // default export is correct

See Communicate from OmniScript to a Lightning Web Component and import for more information.

Thanks @sfdcfox for pointing that out. I was able to resolve the issue by importing it that way.
